# Create table and button in a single layout

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to create a table and a button in a single layout using pyqt5 in python3 .I have created a button and then a table but table is hiding the button . I need to make both button and table to appear in a single layout . I dont need pyqtdesigner answer i want to do in pyqt5 only .

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QApplication,
                             QLabel, QAction, QMainWindow, qApp, QFileDialog, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem)
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QRect

import sys

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, dialog):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        #self.setupUi(dialog)

        self.setWindowTitle('Testing ')
        button = QPushButton('PyQt5 button', self)
        button.setToolTip('This is an example button')
        button.move(100, 70)

        # table

        self.setGeometry(870, 20, 400, 400)
        wid = QWidget(self)
        self.createTable()
        self.setCentralWidget(wid)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        wid.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.home()

    def home(self):
        self.show()


    def close_application(self):
        sys.exit()


    def createTable(self):
        # Create table
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QRect(310, 10, 311, 161))
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (1,1)"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (1,2)"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (2,1)"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (2,2)"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (3,1)"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (3,2)"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (4,1)"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (4,2)"))
        self.tableWidget.move(0, 0)
        self.tableWidget.doubleClicked.connect(self.on_click)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        print("\n")
        for currentQTableWidgetItem in self.tableWidget.selectedItems():
            print(currentQTableWidgetItem.row(), currentQTableWidgetItem.column(), currentQTableWidgetItem.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    dialog = QMainWindow()
    foo = MyMainWindow(dialog)
    foo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am getting only this kind of output . I need to make both button and table appear in a single dialog box

[image]

I am getting a output like this

[image]

I want to make both button and table to a particular size like below picture
output:

[image]

Comment: Add the button to the layout: `self.layout.addWidget(button)` either below or above the line `self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)` depending on whether you want the button below or above the table.

Comment: @Heike Thanks it worked but both button and table are occupying entire windows width and height .Even if i use button.resize(40,40) i am not able to control the width of both button and table

Comment: also @Heike i am not able to adjust size of table also i tried set geomentry()

Comment: If you use a layout you cannot set resize the widgets by hand but you can influence the behaviour of the layout manager for example by setting the alignment or stretch factors of the widgets in your layout.

Comment: @ajith: read the [documentation about layouts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html). Despite being mainly intended for, c++ developers, the concepts are the same for pyqt.

Comment: @Ajith You could show a picture of what you want to get.

Comment: @eyllanesc , musicamante, Heike i have added the picture i want a answer for that type of picture

Comment: @Ajith According to what you show, you don't need any QXLayout so remove it from your code and only use `widget.setGeometry(x, y, w, h)`, why do you think you should use a QXLayout?

Comment: @eyllanesc could you write and post it as answer i am not able to get you .Without layout i wont be able to add the tablewidget . I am new to pyqt5 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be able to set the geometry of widgets freely, they cannot be added to a layout, but they *need* to have a parent (the widget inside which they will be shown). You weren't able to "add" the tablewidget without the layout because you created it without assigning it a parent.

Using a QMainWindow requires some care also, because it has its own internal layout (which is used to add specific widgets for a mainwindow like the menu bar, the status bar and dock/toolbars), so it's always better to set a [`centralWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#centralWidget) and use that as a parent for child widgets. For more information, read the [Qt Main Window Framework documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#details).

```
class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, dialog):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setWindowTitle('Testing ')
        self.setGeometry(870, 20, 400, 400)

        central = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central)

        button = QPushButton('PyQt5 button', central)
        button.setToolTip('This is an example button')
        button.move(100, 70)

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self.centralWidget())
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QRect(310, 10, 311, 161))
```

There's a catch. Using "free" widgets is usually discouraged, especially if a window can be resized, by the user or by the system (for example if the screen is not big enough), potentially hiding part of the interface. And that's what you actually did by setting the geometry in the first place. By running the code above (with the geometry you set in your example), this is the result:

[image: table hidden]

While you could force the window size with `setWindowSize()`, this is discouraged too in this case: different systems and platforms draw widgets with different sizes, and you could end up with an interface that seems to look fine on your computer, while it's not on somebody else's.

If you want a pseudo-fixed layout that resembles what you have shown, you should use layouts anyway, then add *spacings* to the layout. Spacings can be added by adding empty QWidgets that act as spacers, QSpacerItems, or a stretch (that is possible for box layouts, for grid layouts you'll need to create empty columns and rows and set their stretch).

```
class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, dialog):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setWindowTitle('Testing ')

        central = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central)

        mainLayout = QHBoxLayout(central)
        # add a left "margin"
        mainLayout.addStretch(1)

        buttonLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(buttonLayout)

        # add a top "margin"
        buttonLayout.addStretch(1)

        button1 = QPushButton('button 1')
        buttonLayout.addWidget(button1, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)
        button2 = QPushButton('button 2')
        buttonLayout.addWidget(button2, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)

        # add a bottom "margin"
        buttonLayout.addStretch(1)

        # add a "spacing" between the two vertical layouts
        mainLayout.addStretch(1)

        tableLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(tableLayout)

        # add a top "margin" to the right layout
        tableLayout.addStretch(1)

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self.centralWidget())
        tableLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.tableWidget.setFixedSize(311, 161)

        tableLayout.addStretch(1)

        # add a margin to the right
        mainLayout.addStretch(1)

        self.setFixedSize(600, 300)
```

And this is the result:

[image: better widget layout]